# Page loads different versions when pressing Ctrl+R

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, twitter-bootstrap, caching, asset-pipeline

I have a problem with the page which I edit from my site admin (no CMS used), it have different versions based on all edits by admin user (me).
When I go to that page on the site as normal user (who available only to view public webpage, not to edit), and press Ctrl+R(refresh page) several times sometimes it loads (oops!) old version of the page with no sequence and sometimes shows 404 error page (like "page not found"). What's that magic and where I should look to fix it? I see no problem neither in Unicorn production.log, nor in browser logs. Tried different browsers from different machines (even that never opened my site before), clearing cookies&cache in browser, even going to that "magic" page from my iPhone - result was the same - strange behaviour.
Could you please tell me how to fix or at least where to look up for fixing this problem?

Comment: You should limit the problem to a specific component/function/module/... and than post some code. Nobody will be able to guess what goes wrong. Since nobody except you knows the problem, no one will be able to tell you "where to look". I'd say start with some more debugging to limit the problems.